# Smooth Animation before NSTimer, But now it's Glitchy

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, rotation, nstimer

I have a `UIImageView` rotating forever on my screen... I use the code below, which I found HERE:

```
- (void) spinWithOptions: (UIViewAnimationOptions) options {
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.0f
                          delay: 0.0f
                        options: options
                     animations: ^{
                         Hand.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(Hand.transform, M_PI / 30);
                     }
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             if (animating) { //if, keep spinning
                                 [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
                             } else if (options != UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) { //final spin
                                 //[self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut];
                             }
                         }
                     }];
}

- (void) startSpin {
    if (!animating) {
        animating = YES;
        [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn];
    }
}

- (void) stopSpin {
    animating = NO;
}
```

It worked find and the rotation seems smooth...

I've since added a countdown timer, using the follow:

```
-(void)timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer{
    ticks -= 0.1;   //NSLog(@"Total Ticks: %.2f",ticks);

    if(ticks < 0.0){ //3 seconds is up
        Failed.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Failed.png"];
        ticks = 0.0;
        [self GameOver]; //out of time...
    }
    else {
        FailedBeforeTimer.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Failed Before.png"];
    }
    CountDownTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",ticks];
}

-(void)startTimer{
    ticks = 3.0;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)stopTimer{
    [timer invalidate];
    ticks = 0.0;
}
```

Since adding this timer to my app, the rotation animation is really blocky and no longer a smooth rotation...

Any ideas what I should implement to solve this?

To check, I removed the timer and re-run the application, and sure enough, the animation was smooth again :(

**UPDATE:**

After some more trial and error, it seems to be this line of code that slows the process down: `CountDownTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",ticks];` ie. When I don't display the countDownTimer text on the screen/update label on screen), the rotation is smooth still...

So confused... What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animating with zero-duration animations does not make sense. That's not how UIView animation is supposed to work. My guess is that is the source of your problems. A zero duration animation will be jumpy by definition.

You should be animating your changes over some time-period. (Always use a non-zero duration.)

### EDIT:

Note that your timerTick method is horribly inefficient. You load the same image into an image view on every tick. Don't do that. Set it up with the initial image, and then only change the image when your tick count reaches zero.

Comment: If I use anything other than zero, it's really slow?

Comment: Animation animates a change over time. You should not use repeated calls to `animateWithDuration` with changes in a value to animate something. You should make one `animateWithDuration` call that sets the final value of your animation and the system takes care of everything.

Comment: Using the method I did above, it rotates really slowly. I found it on another question here and the duration was set to 1.0f, but I slowly made the number smaller to increase the rotation speed... I'm not sure the best way to rotate a UIImageView, quickly AND keep track of the rotation...

Comment: Try  duration of .1 second and a rotation value of M_PI/2. That will rotate your image a quarter-turn every 1/10 second, or a full turn every 1/5 second. That should be plenty fast enough, no?

Comment: The problem with that it, the screen is tapped to stop the rotation, at which point the rotation angle is compared to a target and then you either hit the target or didn't... with M_PI/2, there's only 4 comparable angles? It's basically a clock hand, and it rotates and you have to tap it when you pass the highlighted number to score a point...

Comment: You should probably use CADisplayLink synchronized to the screen display, and rotate your image a single step (not animated) on each screen refresh then, by explicitly changing the view's transform.

Comment: I'll have to try and find an example... the only ones I've found previously suggest this method of the CABasicAnimation method. But the later doesn't allow me to track it.

Answer (score 2):

You should give `CADisplayLink` a try, it should be suitable for your case. It's easy to use, there are heaps of tutorials out there, just do a search.